# Objective increasing while error decreasing in CNN

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using MatConvNet to train a convolutional neural network, and i noticed that after the 5th iteration, the objective started fluctuating (mostly upwards) whereas the validation error was decreasing. Does this indicate overlearning? What system parameters can I change for a slower but more steady learning?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

When the network starts overfitting, it is generally the other way around: the training error keeps decreasing whereas the validation error increases or stagnates. In your case, you can play with different learning rates and annealing schedules, momentum, or use Batch Normalization (http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).